# Splunk Dashboard Query To Retrieve & Count List of Items

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I'm a complete Splunk newbie and have a log statement that logs a `List<String>` of ID's from my Java application i.e.

```
log.info("ID's are {}", idList);
```

Using the Splunk Enterprise Dashboard, i want to display a Single Value as a count which would represent the total number of entries in the list and also display the list of ID's in a separate table view.

Using the `Search with SPL` option in the Dashboard, i get one row using the following:

```
sourceType="cf:logmessage" AND cf_app_name=my_app 
| regex msg="MyClass.ID's are"
| stats sum(linecount) as Total
```

The question is, how do I access the `idList` to iterate it to count the total number of items and also print each item from the list in a separate table view?

Comment: https://lantern.splunk.com/Splunk_Platform/Product_Tips/Searching_and_Reporting/Working_with_multivalue_fields#Makemv_command